# React - How to test image onload or onerror in 2021

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jsdom

I'm using react-tesing-lib for my testing, and I have an image component which shares accross the project. I'm trying to test the component using default CRA build with `jsdom`. Turns out this bit difficult to implement, I checked few resources.

I updated jest(26.6.0) and jsdom(16.6.0) to latest version. Also I've tried with `canvas` `jest-canvas-mock` lib as well

Here is my sample code, Also I've uploaded in here as well.

Image.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Image({ src = "" }) {
  const [status,setStatus] = useState("Loading")
  const handleOnLoad = () => {
    setStatus("handleOnLoad");
  };
  
  const handleOnError = () => {
    setStatus("handleOnError");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {status}
      <img alt={status} width="50" src={src} onLoad={handleOnLoad} onError={handleOnError} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Image.test.js

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import "jest-canvas-mock";

import Image from "./Image";

describe('Test', () => {
  it("Image shouldss render correctly", async () => {
    render(<Image src="LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC" />);

    await screen.findByText(/handleOnLoad/i);
  });
})
```

In the end, `jsdom` not able to excute the on events. based on this [comment](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-310106280)

> Browsers do not fire a load event when they are configured to not load images. jsdom is by default configured to not load any external resources, so it follows browsers in this regard. This brings images in line with other not-loaded resources (like video, audio, link rel=preload, etc.)

Here is full [source code](https://gofile.io/d/Rml4c8)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which works but I don't think this can be counted as a recommended one.
You need to manually trigger `onError` on image by accessing its internal props like this:

```
render(<Image src="LOAD_SUCCESS_SRC" />);

const image = screen.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

const propsKey = Object.keys(image).find((key) =>
  key.startsWith('__reactProps')
);

act(() => {
  image[propsKey].onError();
});

waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.queryByText(/handleOnLoad/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```